# Can minus zero programmatically exist?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have two numbers which are in binary. And I want to add a=(-0) and b=(-0) and if I add numbers i get nothing in output. I want an output (-0) without converting to decimal. Is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
 int b1, b2;
            int i = 0, rem = 0;
            int[] sum = new int[20];
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the first binary number: ");
            b1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the second binary number: ");
            b2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (b1 != 0 || b2 != 0)
            {
                sum[i++] = (b1 % 10 + b2 % 10 + rem) % 2;
                rem = (b1 % 10 + b2 % 10 + rem) / 2;
                b1 = b1 / 10;
                b2 = b2 / 10;
            }
            if (rem != 0)
                sum[i++] = rem;
            --i;
            Console.WriteLine("Sum of two binary numbers: ");
            while (i <= 0)
                Console.Write("{0}", sum[i--]);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: `-0` does not exists thanks to 2's compliment.

Comment: -0 is called a [signed zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero), it's technically a negative number but it's practically the exact same as 0.

Comment: There is no such thing as -0 when dealing with integers. 0 is 0. Besides, what do you mean "the numbers are binary"?

Comment: input of numbers are in binary

Comment: Are you saying you're expecting the user to enter, for example, the string `10010`? If so, you're going to have a big problem with the integer division lines `b1 = b1 / 10` and `b2 = b2 / 10`.

Comment: Can you implement output -0 using different code?

Comment: Is your question simply "How do I display a negative sign in front of the 0 if the answer is 0?"

Comment: @RexJones - Please use the "@" notifications to let us know which comment you are replying to and to send a notification to the user you're responding to.

Comment: @RexJones - Awesome. I got the notification. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so based in your answers, it sounds like you want to display a negative sign in front of the answer if your answer is zero, which I assume this happens when every element in your `sum` array is the value `0`.

*Before* your last `while` loop you can insert this piece of code:

```
if (Array.TrueForAll(sum, n => n == 0))
    Console.Write("-");
```

This will print a negative sign if and only if every element in the `sum` array is the value 0. Note that this code belongs *outside* your last while loop.

I should also point out that your last while loop's condition should probably be `while (i >= 0)`.

Comment: It goes to infinite loop. Thanks anyways.

Comment: What does? The code I pasted above? it definitely does not. Where did you paste my code?

Comment: while (i <= 0)
                {
                    if (Array.TrueForAll(sum, n => n == 0))
                         Console.Write("-");
                        Console.Write("{0}", sum[i--]);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

Comment: As I said, the if condition should be *outside* the while loop. Also, your while loop's condition is incorrect. Please see my edits.

Comment: I corrected the code. But then it does not give any output

Comment: That's a different issue than your original question, so please create another question.